# Why is a method of superinterface called through Interface.super?

Tags: java

When you extend a class in Java you can refer to base class' members through the `super` reference. However when you have a class `A`, that `implements` and interface `B`, you can only refer to `B`'s methods in this way `B.super.method()`. Why does the `super` keyword in the second case have to be prefixed with `B.`?

Example:

```
interface Runner {
    default void run() {
        System.out.println("default Runner::run");
    }
}

static class RunnerImpl implements Runner {
    public void run() {
        Runner.super.run(); // doesn't work without "Runner."
    }
}
```

Comment: Its a question of why do you even call it? Its default - as such you don't need to implement in RunnerImpl it if you want to use default one.

Comment: @Worthless It's an example to illustrate the question It's not uncommon to run a default implementation and then your own custom code (which is not shown in the post)

Comment: You can have interface Runner2 with the same default method.

Comment: In theory it would be possible to allow `super` to refer to superinterfaces in case it's not ambiguous, but it would make the rules unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because interfaces allow multiple inheritance, which can result in ambiguity for identical methods:

```
interface Runner1 {
    default void run() {
        System.out.println("default Runner1::run");
    }
}

interface Runner2 {
    default void run() {
        System.out.println("default Runner2::run");
    }
}

static class RunnerImpl implements Runner1, Runner2 {
    public void run() {
        super.run(); // which one???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Because `super.xyz()` looks in the superclass (which you don't have, besides `Object`) and `Type.super.xyz()` will look for a class or interface, as defined in [15.12.1. Compile-Time Step 1: Determine Class or Interface to Search](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12):

> If the form is `super . [TypeArguments] Identifier`, then the class to search is the superclass of the class whose declaration contains the method invocation.

Notice, no interface mentioned.

> If the form is `TypeName . super . [TypeArguments] Identifier`, then:
>
> [...]
>
> Otherwise, `TypeName` denotes the interface to be searched, I.

Comment: Also, when "TypeName" is a class and not an interface, `TypeName.super` refers to the superclass of the _enclosing class_.